# Where to find ready to use CLR dlls for SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

There are a lot of standard tasks, which are not part of T-SQL, e.g.

- string concatenate  aggregate function
- regex string compare

are there location where I can download recompiled dlls and get with installation instructions.

I'm not interested in compiling those dlls myself.

**Edit:**

The answers motivated me to change my attitude concerning compiling the CLR dlls myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, you'd generally have to compile yourself because of .net versions, or 32/64 bit etc.

Comment: Who downvoted this? I think gbn is right when he means that one has to learn to compile the such dll by oneself, when one wants to use them. A general pool of dll's seems missing.

Comment: @bernd_k: thanks. I would search to find the code I wanted, review it, and then compile it for my platform. For RegEx, it's quite common and Red-Gate has several others too

Answer (score 0):

A quick google came up with [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlclrlib/).

> The SqlClr Library is a collection of CLR routines written in C# for MS Sql Server 2005 database programmers. This project augments TSQL (aka T-SQL or Transact SQL) functionality. Providing the database programmer with more tools.

Though it doesn't have any released files.

There is also [this](http://mssqlclr.com/) site, which only has a single RegEx library.

[Here](http://fotiasqlclr.codeplex.com/releases/view/27941) is another CodePlex project that actually has some files - mostly string manipulation and formatting from a quick glance:

> The Fotia SQLCLR library contains indispensable SQL Server 2008 user-defined functions and aggregates written in C#.

Comment: Fotia seems to be a codeplex project not giving away its sources and a clear description of the functions included is missing - strange.

Comment: @bernd_k - I didn't see that, sorry.

Comment: RegEx library comes with sources. That looks interesting.